# Background Image Scaling

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having a problem, pretty much what i'm trying to do is make my background image stay anchored and remain the same size and position not matter how larger the users resolution.

What I have now:

```
#navigator {
    background-image: url('banner.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top-center;
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `background-size`?

```
#navigator {
    background-image: url('banner.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top-center;
    background-size: 200pt 300pt;
}
```

(as from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

It will work for most modern browsers compatible with CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to learn about the meta viewport options. One that I use all the time is `target-densitydpi`, this is Android specific.
`<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me,

```
html, body, <or your div>
 {
    background-image:url("fdkljg.kdf");
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

and if that doesn't work, try out the "background-position" property to center or left.
and once you are done with the code, try zooming in and out the web page to simulate the screen resolution.